# how trait and inheritence practically different?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, traits

I know an abstract class can have a hierarchy or tree that we dn't want to so we use trait that is more like a way to write duplicate code once and including in different classes. But what if abstract class also don't have hierarchy.

What if I am going to have a class with only some reusable logic, let's assume we don't need multiple traits. So how exactly we should choose between these two.

Methods in both abstract class and trait can be overridden in same way. So in short, we can utilize these two for each other.

For example:

```
class MyController{
   use RestCrudTrait;
   public function store(){
       //override here
   }
}
```

and

```
class MyController extends RestCrudController{
    public function store(){
       //override here
   }
}
```

I have tried them both they can be used in this way interchangably. Also i have placed here controller, it can be model or something else. So how exactly one need to choose from using Trait or extending class.

If inheritance is not good due to those hierarchies etc. then one can always use Trait then when inheritance?

So what I want to know is :

1. Whether these two just logically different and can actually do same things and can be interchangeably use?
2. Even if they are logically different then how should one choose between these two?

Comment: The whole point of traits is to let you inherit from multiple trees. If you don't need that, there's no point defining a trait.

Comment: @rjdown trait doesn't represent a tree but I think what you want to say is to inherit different functionalities. But at time of starting a class like in example above, when at start we have only one thing to inherit or functionality to have then how to decide whether trait or inheritance?

Comment: I think you have misread what I said. Either way, traits are merely there to help (as the manual puts it) "group functionality in a fine-grained and consistent way". Again, if you don't need it, don't use it.

Comment: @rjdown how to decide whether i need it or not? I may use it so that I can always have more trait or get class inherited by something else. In that way traits sound like simple choice but that mentality will result in always usage or trait. Then when inheritance?

Comment: If you are creating a class and realise you need to use functionality from two different other classes (with a different base class), then you would use a trait. If you are creating a class that will use the functionality from a single class, then consider if you even need a new one in the first place. If you do, just extend.

Answer (score 1):

I think traits are a serious double edge sword, on one hand you can duplicate code as you said, in the other hand, you can loose a huge readability in the process.

In my opinion, I would only use traits for simple interface implementation, like a ServiceManagerAwareInterface which would has only a getter and setter, and a trait ServiceManagerAwareTrait, it will carry implementation to avoid writing getter and setter logic in every class implementing my Interface.

in that way, it helps a little while using interface segregation principle.

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually almost always go for composition over inheritance or trait usage if I wanted to reuse code. While traits might seem a good addition to the language, they're really no better than having properties of a class `new`ed directly inside the class itself, rather than being injected from the outside.

In both cases (that is when you use either a trait or extend a class) you create a very tight coupling between the two elements (consumer of the trait or the child of a supertype respectively).

### Why is this bad?

Well first of all, you're limited to only one way how you can construct an object graph.

No matter what you'll do, the `MyController` will always be directly linked to either `RestCrudTrait` or `RestCrudController`.

Also, and this may not be your case, with both traits and inheritance, you may be poluting the public API with methods which you don't want the class consuming the trait or extenting a parent have.

---

Anyway, in most frameworks inheritance is profoundly used (when a custom controller extends the one acting as a supertype) because frameworks use dynamic lookup, checking the available methods of the user-made controller if a route or an action may be accessed.

In a scenario like that, I'd definitely go for inheritance, because you need to work around the constraint presented by the environment.

If you are not limited to any constraints and what you want is simple code reuse without having to manually inject components into your classes and expose the methods of these components through a facade of the class taking these dependencies, then I'd go for a trait.

Still, it has proven to me that the few more lines of a code where you need to take a dependency, assign it to a private variable and expose only what you really need, was usually a better idea, not only but mostly for testing (to create low coupling).